# How to grouping data from observable by nested key?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I build a new application and I have problem with grouping data :/ Basically this data comes from observable and I need group objects by status and push it to an array. I tried use groupBy() but it didn't work.

This is what I have:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 3424234,
    name: "asdfgasdgas",
    protocol: 235452345,
    status: {
      code: "AVAILABLE",
      displayName: "Available"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 543534,
    name: "regertjerg",
    protocol: 7745672345,
    status: {
      code: "AVAILABLE",
      displayName: "Available"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 96089678,
    name: "kluioliudas",
    protocol: 7878745,
    status: {
      code: "INITIALREVIEW", 
      displayName: "Initial review"
    }
  }
]
```

and this is what I want...:

```
const result = [
  {
    code: "AVAILABLE",
    displayName: "Available",
    items: [
      {
        id: 3424234,
        name: "asdfgasdgas",
        protocol: 235452345
      },
      {
        id: 543534,
        name: "regertjerg",
        protocol: 7745672345
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    code: "INITIALREVIEW", 
    displayName: "Initial review",
    items: [
      {
        id: 96089678,
        name: "kluioliudas",
        protocol: 7878745
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce()` method as shown below:

```
result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.status.code] = r[a.status.code] || [];
        r[a.status.code].push(a);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
```

Here we are grouping by the status.code

Comment: is not the result requested by OP

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
 

const data = [ { id: 3424234, name: "asdfgasdgas", protocol: 235452345, status: { code: "AVAILABLE", displayName: "Available" } }, { id: 543534, name: "regertjerg", protocol: 7745672345, status: { code: "AVAILABLE", displayName: "Available" } }, { id: 96089678, name: "kluioliudas", protocol: 7878745, status: { code: "INITIALREVIEW", displayName: "Initial review" } } ] 

const groupBy = (arr) => data.reduce((acc, ele)=>( (acc[ele.status.code] = acc[ele.status.code] || []).push(ele), acc),{})

const reformat = ([k, v]) => ({code: k, displayName: v[0].status.displayName, items: v.map(({id, name, protocol})=>({id, name, protocol}))})
  
const result  =  Object.entries(groupBy(data)).map(ele=> reformat(ele))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I can't use `reformat` because I don't have const interface. So your solution should be work in any data but at this moment it's not

Answer (score 1):

This might be the easy and understandable one.

```
let arr = [];
let statuses = [];
data.forEach(x => {
    if(!arr.find(code => code == x.status.code)) {
        arr.push(x.status.code);
        statuses.push(x.status);
    }
})
let result = statuses.map((xs:any) => {
    xs.items = data.filter(y => y.status.code == xs.code)
    return xs;
})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: status field  is still displayed in your result